# Can't all import - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

First, the purpose is to get these views.

```html
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/Hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="100dp" />
```

This way I can bring it.

```html
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.Hello)
```

But I want to import the entire XML file at once.
So I thought that typing Hello. would be an automatic import function, but it doesn't work.
Is there any way to solve this?
The alt+enter method did not solve it.

What is displayed by saying alt+enter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR3cY.jpg)

Comment: I recommend you to learn viewBinding do some research on it it will help you to reduce your boiler plate code

Answer (score 0):

Typing "Hello" wont work as you have assigned the name 'textView' to that particular TextView,
I recommend changing the code to `val Hello: TextView = findViewById(R.id.Hello)`